# Cant install webpack and babel on ubuntu

Tags: babeljs

I have this exception in CLI

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

Comment: That is a warning, not an error. It should still work.

Comment: but i cant build my project

Comment: What error are you getting when you actually build? If that's the issue, you should ask that question instead :)